# How to architecture an alarm engine?

Tags: iot, rules, alarm, aws-iot, rule-engine

I'm looking to develop and/or implement an existing solutions an Alarm Engine preferably around AWS and/or PHP eco-systems.

Precisely I have a stream of messages containing values and I need to define rules like:

- Temperature has been greater than 100 F° for a period of 5 minutes

And dispatch a message if the rule matches.

I'm looking to do something very similar to Grafana Alarms or CloudWatch Alarms on AWS.

I've not been able to find a standalone service or library to do that.

The rules engines doesn't seems that hard, however given the fact that there is a period to take care of, it seems somewhat more complicated because we need to take care of a transient state.

Any clues?

Comment: Make your application publish CloudWatch metrics using the SDK in your target language and then leverage native CloudWatch alarms - are you aware of publishing [custom CW metrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/publishingMetrics.html)?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I've though about this but since alerts must be manageable on a per client basis and the volume may be important I don't think "tricking" CW would be a solution.

Comment: You didn't mention clients?